# Internal thickness for the border of a button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the border of a button internal, so that the button won't modify it's spacings.

When the size of the button border is increased, I want it to not affect the other elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="text1">Some text 1</div>
<button class="button">Button</button>
<div class="text2">Some text 2</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text1,
.text2,
.button {
    display:inline;
}
.text1,
.text2 {
    padding:2px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
button {
    background-image:none;
    border:4px solid blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ow67a8o6/

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box` should so that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-sizing:border-box` should so that for you.

Also, `inline-block` is usually better than `inline` but it depends on your use case.

```css
.text1,
.text2,
.button {
  display: inline-block;
}
.text1,
.text2 {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
button {
  background-image: none;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="text1">Some text 1</div>
<button class="button">Button</button>
<div class="text2">Some text 2</div>
```

**Alternative**

Don't use a border, use an inset box-shadow

```css
.text1,
.text2,
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
button {
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px blue;
  border: none;
}
button:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="text1">Some text 1</div>
<button class="button">Button</button>
<div class="text2">Some text 2</div>
```

Comment: I see that if you increase the size of the border it still gets outside. What I want is that the border increase it's size internally so that it can cover the text

Comment: Added `box-shadow` option